# SQL Query to find out matching column combination between 2 tables

Tags: sql

I would like to know the query for the following case.

```
Table 1 :         Table 2

Col1    Col2    Col1    Col2
Sandy    1     Sandy     24
Reena    2     Reena     32
Swathi   3     Swathi    3
Reenu    4     Karthik   5
               Reenu     4
               Muthu     6
```

the query should **return:**

1. The rows in table 2 that is not in table 1 ( Karthik and Muthu rows should be the result)
2. It shoudl compare the column combination and should return the changed column combination.

Finally i should get the following **result :**,

```
Table1.Col1 Table1.col2 Table2.col2
Sandy         1          24
Reena         2          32
Karthik      NA          5
Muthu        NA          6
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you attempted any part of the query yet?

Comment: Create a SQL fiddle, and make an attempt....

Answer (score 1):

```
select t2.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2 as t2c
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
where t1.Col2 is null or t1.Col2 <> t2.Col2
```

if you want explicitely 'NA', you should do something like this (function depending on your dbms)

```
coalesce(<somefunctionToConvertinttostring>(t1.col2), 'NA')
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6830c/3)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col2 
from Table2 a left join Table1 b on a.Col1=b.Col1 
where b.Col1 is null

union

select a.Col1, a.Col2, b.Col2 
from Table2 a inner join Table1 b on a.Col1=b.Col1 
where a.Col2<>b.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat both queries with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Table1.Col1 AS T1Col1, 
       Table2.col1 AS T2Col1, 
       Table2.col2 As T2Col2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 
WHERE Table1.Col2 <> Table2.Col2

UNION ALL 

SELECT COALESCE(Table1.Col1,'NA') AS T1Col1, 
       Table2.col1 AS T2Col1, 
       Table2.col2 As T2Col2
FROM Table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1
  ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 
WHERE Table1.Col1 IS NULL
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21f78/9/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

select c3,ISNULL(C2,'NA') AS C2,c4 from Table1  right join
Table2 on Table1 .c1 = Table2.C3
WHERE ISNULL(Table1.c2,0) <> Table2.C4

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain why this works?